# Is there a better way to populate userform comboboxes with the data from the active row when it initializes? Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

The code below works PERFECTLY in Excel 2010, but for some reason hardly ever works right in Excel 2013.

The point is that when a cell is double clicked (code not here, works fine in both 2010 and 2013 tho), a userform will pop up with the data of the "active row." When I do this in excel 2013, the userform will pop up, but it will either have data from a different row or all comboboxes will be blank. There are no debugging issues or notifications.

Here is what works in 2010 and not in 2013:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call UnProtect

Dim r As Integer
r = ActiveCell.Row

StatusBox.Clear

With StatusBox                    
    .AddItem "New"
    .AddItem "In Process"
    .AddItem "Waiting on Material/Parts"
    .AddItem "Re-Assigned"
    .AddItem "Complete"
End With


'When the userform pops up, it automatically has the
'data from the row that has been double clicked
LocationValue.Value = Open_Orders.Cells(r, 2).Value
AssetValue.Value = Open_Orders.Cells(r, 3).Value
DescriptionValue.Value = Open_Orders.Cells(r, 10).Value
CommentBox.Value = Open_Orders.Cells(r, 11).Value
StatusBox.Value = Open_Orders.Cells(r, 8).Value

'LocationValue, AssetValue, DescriptionValue, CommentBox, and StatusBox are all
'either a combobox or textbox 



Call Protect
End Sub
```

I have only been using vba for a short time, so I'm sure this is the completely wrong way to do it. Is there a better way?

EDIT: Here is the code that is placed in the sheet called Open_Orders:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Sheets("Open_Orders").Protect Password:="password", userinterfaceonly:=True

Dim TheRow As Integer
TheRow = LastRow(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K1"))
        '^Function found in "LastRowFunction" module
        'Determines the last row that contains data in it

Set rng = Range("B2:K" & TheRow)

'If you click a cell with data in it then show the userform

If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Load UserComment
UserComment.Show
Sheets("Open_Orders").Activate

End Sub
```

UserComment is the userform that pops up, and is supposed to have the data from the active row.

Comment: We are missing a lot of information here. Without the full code we have no clue of what Open_Orders for example. Also I would say that your "r" is addressing a wrong activecell, but it's just my guess

Comment: I've edited my original post with more info/code.

Comment: I don't understand the last 4 lines: is your UserComment always supposed to appear (also when I click for example on "A1")?

Comment: It only (and is only supposed to) appear  when you click anywhere from B2 through K&TheRow, where TheRow is the last row that contains data.

Comment: but if you put an `If... Then` on a line without a `End If` doesn't it stop with `Load UserComment`? I mean, what's below (`UserComment.Show`) will always be executed... or not?

Comment: If I have an End If I get a compile error "End If without block If" The userform DOES show with how the code is written now.

Comment: O_O strange.
Line 1: `If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then` (you can show UserForms without loading them too)
Line 2: `UserComment.Show`
Line 3: `Sheets("Open_Orders").Activate`
Line 4: `End If`

Did you write so?

Comment: Yes, that works with my excel 2010 on this machine. I will have to try it on 2013. But will this affect how it initializes and loads data into combo boxes? Showing the userform has never been an issue...

Comment: I have the 2013 and use this commands daily. Yes, it will affect your comboboxes, because before if you selected a random cell, it would trigger the UserForm to activate, therefore getting a random row. Try the code out and tell me

Comment: No, it still populates the comboboxes with the wrong data from a row that i did not click. Only does this for 2013. Still works great in 2010. This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Some other idea then, what does your "UnProtect" do? that will be executed after the activecell row is stored in your macro. Try to put the assignment before the UnProtect

Comment: Its a macro that unprotects the sheet with the password and sets screenupdates to false. But ok I will try that too.

Comment: Please tell me if it worked (possibly in combination to what I said before)

Comment: @Noldor130884 That seems to do the trick. Getting rid of the protect/unprotect macros for the initialize and making the 4 lines you said has worked for my machine with 2013 on it.

Comment: Writing it as an answer then. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
Call UnProtect

Dim r As Integer
r = ActiveCell.Row

StatusBox.Clear
```

Your `UnProtect` Macro will probably return a row that is not the one you want when you write:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Load UserComment
UserComment.Show
Sheets("Open_Orders").Activate
```

I also find these very lines somehow not very clear, as the `UserComment.Show` will work anyway since you didn't specify and `End If`there. I'd write:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then 
    UserComment.Show
    Sheets("Open_Orders").Activate
End If
```